# Output the average percentage marks obtained by that particular student, correct to two decimal places

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

This question was asked in hackerrank. Well, I see the discussion tab but I like to do it in more my way. But I'm getting the wrong output

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input())
student_marks = {}
for _ in range(n):
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores
query_name = input()
sum=0

for key, value in student_marks.items():
    if query_name == value:
        for i, p in enumerate(scores):
            #sum=0
            sum=sum+p
        per = float(sum/(i+1))
        print("{:.2f}".format(per))
        break
    else:
        print("try again")
```

**So the output I get**

```
--Input (stdin)--
2 
ram 34 56 67
anish 78 98 54
ram
--Your Output (stdout)--
try again
try again
```

I know this process seems long and kind of boring, but I really wanna solve this problem through this logic. Because I've just started learning python.

Comment: add details about how you are calculating the output and also add the expected output

Comment: if you want to find a name is in dictionary you can use `dict.get()` no need of for loop. And problem with your code is you are comparing with the value you need to compare with the key  `query_name == key`. One more thing for calculating sum you can use `sum()` method  `sum(value) / len(value)`

Answer (score 0):

Sidenote: since `sum` is a builtin, you shouldn't override it. Please use another name for variable. 
I see that you use scores variable, which is not correct. So, fixing the `sum` related stuff, you  will come to the following solution:

```
import statistics

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()

    while True:
        try:
            marks = student_marks[query_name]
        except KeyError:
            print("Student does not exist")
        else:
            print("{:.2f}".format(statistics.mean(marks)))
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

For value in items already indicates the marks in the list so you don't need another for loop. This is the solution i came up with. Thanks

```
for i,j in student_marks.items():
    if query_name == i:
        a = 0
        a += sum(j)

        a1 = a/len(j)
        
        print("%.2f" % a1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this same problem on Hackerrank because they don't explain the question well. I hope the below solution helps:

```
# Enter the number of grades a student has:
# for ex. n = 3 for "Malika 52 56 60"
n = int(input())

# NOTE: The below is just data to test this:
# Krishna 67 68 69
# Arjun 70 98 63
# Malika 52 56 60

student_marks = {}

for _ in range(n):
    # Enter the student(s) with their data each time seperately in the "input()" for ex. Malika 52 56 60
    name, *line = input().split()
    scores = list(map(float, line))
    student_marks[name] = scores

# Enter the students name: "Malika"
query_name = input() 

if query_name in student_marks:
    grades = student_marks[query_name]
    average_grade = sum(grades) / len(grades)
    print("{:.2f}".format(average_grade))
else:
    print("Student NOT found.")
```

Doing this just for "Malika" should result in the answer of 56.00

Below I will further explain some of the code used in this solution:

```
name, *line = input().split()
```

1. This line reads in a string from input (the console), splits it into a list of strings at each space character, then assigns the first string in the list to the variable "name", and the rest of the strings to the list "line". The "*" before "line" is used to unpack the remaining strings in the list into "line", so that it contains all the strings except the first one. This is a useful technique when you don't know how many elements you will have in the list.

```
scores = list(map(float, line))
```

2. This line converts the list of strings "line" into a list of floats "scores" using the map() function and the float() function. The map() function applies the float() function to each element in the list, converting it to a float, and returns an iterator that generates the converted values. The list() function is then used to create a new list from the iterator, containing all the converted float values.

```
student_marks[name] = scores
```

3. This line adds the student's name "name" as a key to the empty "student_marks" dictionary, and sets its value to the list of scores "scores". This allows us to store the scores for each student in a dictionary, using their names as keys.

These three lines of code are used to read in the name and scores for a student from input(), convert the scores to floats, & store them in a dictionary with the student's name as the key.